# I don't know if my media queries are correct

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm currently trying to build a responsive site and getting stuck at these media queries. So this is my issue.

```
.safehouse-sub {
     color: #000000; 
     text-align: justify;
}

@media(min-width: 900px) {
.safehouse-sub {
     color: #000000; 
     text-align: justify;
     }
}  

@media(max-width: 900px) {
.safehouse-sub { 
    color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
    }
}
```

This code gives me the desired effect, but if I remove

```
@media(min-width: 900px) {
.safehouse-sub {
     color: #000000; 
     text-align: justify;
     }
}
```

then it only uses

```
@media(max-width: 900px) {
.safehouse-sub { 
    color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
    }
}
```

Why? Shouldn't the native style stay active unless the screen reaches 900px? If not then do I have to have 2 media queries for every style?

Comment: both values are equal at 900px - hence the last rule applies

Comment: If I remove @media(min-width: 900px) {
.safehouse-sub {
     color: #000000; 
     text-align: justify;
     }
} shouldn't it just use .safehouse-sub {
     color: #000000; 
     text-align: justify;
}

Comment: justify is the first rule, center the second. since both are matching 900px the last (second) rule has the final saying. change your values to test, e.g. first 600px, second 900px

Comment: That still doesn't explain why the original class isn't being used if I remove @media(min-width: 900px) {
.safehouse-sub {
     color: #000000; 
     text-align: justify;
     }
} That is what I don't get, why doesn't it justify it until it reaches the 900px breakpoint?

Comment: perhaps you want to try @media screen and(max-device-width:900px)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your media max-width is used under 900px screen, so your code does the opposite of what you want to do.

Answer :

```
.safehouse-sub {
     color: #000000; 
     text-align: justify;
}

@media(min-width: 900px) {
.safehouse-sub { 
    color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
    }
}
```

Comment: I scrawled through the css for about an hour and found that I forgot to a */ on a comment above the beginning of the css and it was causing issues with the first rule. I now understand that the native style is always used unless the conditions for the media query are met. Which means that the native style basically covers > 901px and my media query covers < 900px. It was just a missing comment mark. Thank you for the help and tips though guys, much appreciated.